# A JSON database with behaviour like this file script

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I know that I can parse a json file and then write it down back.
I did it with this nodejs script.

db.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
var database = require('./db.json');

module.exports = database;
module.exports.save = () => {
    // save to json file
    console.log(JSON.stringify(database));
    fs.writeFileSync("./db.json", JSON.stringify(database));
};
```

But there is a database that could do this?
I already know mongodb but it creates file too large for my raspberry pi.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=json+database did you poke around npm?

Comment: @corn3lius 1. it should be like but not a JSON file; 2. i want a standalone database server